# AfterEffects Script - I want to set the display settings of the layer panel with a script

Tags: extendscript, after-effects

halo!
I would like to explain in words, but I am Japanese and rely on Google Translate, so let me explain with pictures.
I would like to implement a script that increases the header like the second image when I press the arrow on the first image.

I'm having trouble finding anyone who can answer that it's the Japanese community.
[1st](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VBBn.png)[2st](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1yGA.png)

Comment: Unfortunately you can't script the UI with extendscript.

Comment: >> stib Thank you for your feedback. I thought so too, but I found a script called "NetaFreak". As far as I can see I think I can...

Comment: If you read the description it does it by saving a copy of the project as an xml file and modifying it. It does the job, but seems very kludgy to me

Comment: The video is a little, well, hype-y. It doesn't work that fast, particularly if you've got a big project.